# Combine enum description with variable arguments

Tags: java, enums

I have ENUM class which I am using it for building the response object some thing like this.

```
    if(statusCode == 0){
            userModel.setResponseCode(BOFAStatusCodes.ACTION_TAKEN.getErrorCode());
            userModel.setResponseMessage(BOFAStatusCodes.ACTION_TAKEN.getDescription());
        }
```

Here is the ENUM.

```
public enum BOFAStatusCodes {
ACTION_TAKEN(0,"An action has been taken that successfully completes the request."),
NO_ACTION(800,"No action was necessary to complete the request successfully."),
AUTH_FAILED(403,"Authentication failed."),
FAILURE_CLIENT(905,"The request cannot be completed due to an error with the client's request."),
FAILURE_SERVICE(500,"The request cannot be completed due to an error with the service's processing of the request.");

private String description;
private int errorCode;

private BOFAStatusCodes(int errorCode, String description){
    this.errorCode=errorCode;
    this.description = description;
}
public int getErrorCode() {
    return errorCode;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
```

}

But now requirement is such that they want userID along with the messages for example:

```
An action has been taken that successfully completes the request for the User XXX.
```

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use String format, in your enum

```
ACTION_TAKEN(0,"An action has been taken that successfully completes the request for the user %s.")
```

and in your class :

```
if(statusCode == 0){
        userModel.setResponseCode(BOFAStatusCodes.ACTION_TAKEN.getErrorCode());
        userModel.setResponseMessage(String.format(BOFAStatusCodes.ACTION_TAKEN.getDescription(), username));
    }
```